# Zoom in Kubuntu app does not display video when I select a virtual background

Tags: kubuntu, video, zoom-meeting

I am on Kubuntu 22.04
I just installed zoom with snap

```
sudo snap install zoom-client
zoom-client 5.17.10.3512 from Oliver Grawert (ogra) installed
```

I opened the app and when I select any other option for virtual background besides `None` there is no video shown.
I test it as follows:

1. I go to my profile settings
2. Go to section `Virtual background`
3. Under the section `Virtual Background` I pick `Blur` or any other of the default ones
4. I close the settings window
5. I click on `New meeting` in the zoom app
6. There is no video shown unless the `Virtual Background` is selected as `None`

Is there any other setting I need to check?